# Exponentiation of a natural number.

Tags: analysis

If $ x \geq y \geq 0$ then $ x^n \geq y^n \geq 0$.

We induct on $n$, for the base case n = 0, $ x^0 = 1 \geq y^0 = 1\geq 0$, this is true, now suppose that $ x^n \geq y^n \geq 0$ for any natural number n, we must show that $ x^{n+1} \geq y^{n+1} \geq 0$.

This is where i... where most people are stuck.

I have tried to split it into separate cases,

so multiplying through by x, we obtain;

$x^{n} \times x \geq y^n \times x $

$x^{n+1}\geq y^n \times x $

and multiplying through by y we obtain;

$x^n \times y\geq y^{n+1} \times x $

could i combine these inequalities? i feel as though i can, but i cant justify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x \ge 0$, so multiplying $x^n \ge y^n$ by $x$ gives you $x^{n+1} \ge x \cdot y^n$.

$y^n \ge 0$, so multiplying $x \ge y$ by $y^n$ gives you $x \cdot y^n \ge y^{n+1}$.

Now you can combine the two inequalities ...

Comment: ah yet another silly decision on my part, thank you Martin.